# How'd I install yii2 advanced on free hosting

Tags: yii2, hosting, cgi-bin, htdocs

After I connect via ftp I have 2 directories: htdocs and cgi-bin
I tried to create a folder inside htdocs and upload yii2 distributive there but i got nothing

Comment: Can you connect via ssh?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka  of course he can't connect -))
 
Tarasovych, read this - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-shared-hosting.md 

or just put in htdocs and edit your `.htaccess`  so `frontend/web/index.php` becomes your front controller.

Comment: @marmeladze but if he just put in htdocs advanced-project-template, directories `frontend/web` and `backend/web` will not `index.php` files? He must start initialize? or am I mistaken?

Comment: если честно, я не понимаю, что ты говоришь. но, положить строку в `.htaccess`, который будет перенаправлять запросы '/' в `frontend/web/ {index.php}` достаточно.

Comment: @marmeladze я говорю что в advanced шаблоне изначально нет файлов `index.php` в `frontend/web` и `backend/web`. Посмотри сам на гитхабе. Чтобы они появились нужно провести инициализацию - [вот так](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#preparing-application) (первый пункт)

Comment: Либо вручную провести её(скопировать нужные файлы из папки `environments`). Но просто добавить .htaccess недостаточно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved via .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdirectory/admin)
RewriteRule ^admin(\/?.*)$ backend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(subdirectory)
RewriteRule ^(\/?.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```